# Consecutive terms which are all prime numbers but are also in AP

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ be in AP with a common difference which is not a multiple of $3$.The maximum number of consecutive terms which are in AP and are also prime numbers is? I thought the answer was $3,5,7$. which gave me the number $3$ but apparently the answer is infinite. How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum is $3$ as you wrote.

If one has four or more terms, then the common difference has to be a multiple of $3$. This is because if the common difference is not a multiple of $3$, then one of $a_2,a_3,a_4$ is a multiple of $3$, not a prime number.

Comment: How exactly did you approach the problem ? I just guessed.An answer in brief steps will be appreciated.

Comment: I was considering in mod $3$ because $3$ is the only prime number which is a multiple of $3$. You can check six cases when the common difference $d$ is not a multiple of $3$ : $d\equiv 1,a_1\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and so on.